# .gitignore not properly white-listing specific files

Tags: git

```
-public/
--dist/
----external/
------external-resource.js
----main.js
----main.css
----favicon.ico
```

I have this directory structure and in my .gitignore I have these entries:

```
public/dist/
!public/dist/favicon.ico
!public/dist/external/
```

I would expect git to ignore the entire public/dist/ directory but white-list the favicon.ico and the entire external/ directory.

I use WebStorm and it colors items that are gitignored in grey. It highlights the favicon.ico and external/ directory making it seem like they are excluded from the gitignore, but git does not see the files.

If I try to issue the command:

```
git add public/dist/favicon.ico
```

It yells says that the file is ignored and that I have to force it to add it.

Why is this happening? Everything I've read makes it seem like my gitignore is correct (even WebStorm)

The version of Git I am using is: 1.9.5.mysysgit.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected. From the gitignore man page:

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

You would instead need to write a rule like:

```
public/dist/*
!public/dist/favicon.ico
```

Here the trailing `*` denotes the difference - you're not ignoring the `dist` directory itself bt rather ignoring everything in it, which is different. Then you can selectively re-include an individual file.

Comment: That'll do it! I wonder why WebStorm was making me believe that it was correct. Must be an oversight in their gitignore parser.